# TableviewDataSource in own file does not conform to protocol UITableViewDataSource in swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, protocols

Error:   `Type "MapListDataSource" does not conform to protocol "UITableViewDataSource"`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MapListDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource    {
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return cell
    }
}
```

I've tried implementing the minimal amount of functions you need to have UITableViewDatasource, still the compiler won't accept it. This is not implemented in the view controller, the data source is split out to its own file. Why is it not conforming to the protocol? Those two methods are the minimal requirement right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add required methods.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
      let cell:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
      return cell
    }
```

Comment: actually had that method but had the old ! from an older implementation. Thanks!